# Visual Studio 2017 automatically checks out file and then back in

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

Running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Version 15.7.6 I'm having a rather annoying problem: Every time I open a file the file get momentarily checked out and back in. This takes a couple of seconds where my IDE freezes.

I haven't changed anything so I'm thinking this might be a bug related to the 15.7.6 release. Has anyone experienced something similar and is there a fix or workaround?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm using TFS for version control. This seems to be happening in all solutions now so I'm thinking that it's VS related and not solution related.

Comment: Did you try in another PC with this version of VS?

Comment: Did some more digging: Doesn't happen for a colleague. It appears to be .cshtml specific. It doesn't happen to .cs or .config files.

Comment: Even more: It happens only to cshtml files with actual Razor code in them. A simple cshtml files without any Razor code is opened just fine.

Comment: Can you reinstall the VS?

Comment: I probably could. But it wouldn't provide an answer :-/ Just tried resetting all my settings and it didn't help.

Comment: You can try to reinstall and also clean the cache folder.

Comment: Reinstalling fixed it... but still... this doesn't provide an answer to what was wrong :-/ Thanks for helping though :-)

Comment: Great :) you can post the solution as an answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it in the end was uninstalling VS2017 and reinstalling it. Even though the installation failed multiple times and I had to delete the VS installer folder, I eventually got it up and running again...